# Error when creating function SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a function so I can take the results of my select statement and place them in a view within our database. My SELECT statement returns one result when I run it, but when I go and place it in to create a function I get the error:

```
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the 
subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

I am still new and learning and would appreciate any help in what I am doing wrong.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CXi_Application 

@Application nvarchar(255), @Wave nvarchar(255)

RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Return int


SET @Return = 
(SELECT @Application, (
(sum(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN effective_score IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN easeuse_score IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + 
(sum(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (2) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN effective_score IN (2) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN easeuse_score IN (2) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)) + 
(sum(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (3) THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN effective_score IN (3) THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN easeuse_score IN (3) THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)) + 
(sum(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (4) THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN effective_score IN (4) THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN easeuse_score IN (4) THEN 4 ELSE 0 END)) + 
(sum(CASE WHEN overall_score IN (5) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN effective_score IN (5) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) + sum(CASE WHEN easeuse_score IN (5) THEN 5 ELSE 0 END)))/
(count(overall_score) + count(effective_score) + count(easeuse_score) * 1.00 )
FROM FY14_DataMerge
WHERE [Status] = 'Completed' AND [Application] = @Application AND [Wave] = @Wave);

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @Return

END
GO
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Run your `SELECT` statement and see how many columns it outputs. You can only have one.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. Thank you for helping me with the obvious. :)

Answer (score 7):

You've specified in the DDL that you'd like the function to return an `INT`

```
RETURNS int
```

however, your result set includes `@Application` and the calculation itself. Essentially, you've declared that you are creating a Scalar-Valued Function but you're code is attempting to return a Table-Valued result. First you need to decide which you'd like to actually do.

If you're returning a single result (commonly found in the `SELECT` portion of the calling statement) then chances are you're looking for a Scalar-Valued function and you need to remove the `@Application` call from your `SELECT` statement in the function DDL.

If you actually would like the value returned from the function then you're going to need a Table-Valued Function. Additionally, this is a pretty straightforward query so you can make it an Inline TVF which has [definite performance benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2554544/251174), though I'm not sure how clearly they will be realized in your case.

Here is what it would look like to make an Inline TVF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CXi_Application 

@Application nvarchar(255), @Wave nvarchar(255)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN SELECT @Application as [Application], (
(sum(CASE overall_score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE effective_score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE easeuse_score WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
    + 
(sum(CASE overall_score WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE effective_score WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE easeuse_score WHEN 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)) 
    + 
(sum(CASE overall_score WHEN 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE effective_score WHEN 3  THEN 3 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE easeuse_score WHEN 3 THEN 3 ELSE 0 END)) 
    + 
(sum(CASE overall_score WHEN 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE effective_score WHEN 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE easeuse_score WHEN 4 THEN 4 ELSE 0 END)) 
    + 
(sum(CASE overall_score WHEN 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE effective_score WHEN 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) 
    + sum(CASE easeuse_score WHEN 5 THEN 5 ELSE 0 END))) 
/
(count(overall_score) + count(effective_score) 
    + count(easeuse_score) * 1.00 ) as CalcMetric
FROM FY14_DataMerge
WHERE [Status] = 'Completed' AND [Application] = @Application AND [Wave] = @Wave;
GO
```

However, if 5 is the max value for each data point, then why not refactor as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CXi_Application 

@Application nvarchar(255), @Wave nvarchar(255)

RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
    SELECT @Application as [Application], 
        (SUM(overall_score) + SUM(effective_score) + SUM(easeuse_score))
          / 
        (count(overall_score) + count(effective_score) 
           + count(easeuse_score) * 1.00 )
        FROM FY14_DataMerge
        WHERE [Status] = 'Completed' 
           AND [Application] = @Application 
           AND [Wave] = @Wave;
GO
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `@Application` thing be aliased for the output, though?

Comment: Thank you so much. I ended up removing the @Application, as I only was using that in the stored procedure for references, and it worked. I appreciate your help.