# Passing each value from temp table to the scalar function and sum values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table valued function.Within that function i have a  this code

```
 DECLARE @totalPayment DECIMAL(18,4)
 DECLARE @totalPaymentConverted DECIMAL(18,4)
 DECLARE @fromCurrencyIdForPaymentSystemsId CHAR(3)

 DECLARE @GetTotalPaymentAmount AS TABLE 
 (
 Amount     DECIMAL(18,4),
 CurrencyId CHAR(3)
 )

INSERT INTO @GetTotalPaymentAmount
SELECT SUM(Amount),CurrencyId
FROM [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
WHERE OperationTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CurrencyId
```

This insert return met table like this

```
 A      C
-----|------
550  |USD
650  |EU
     |
```

I want to pass each of this values Amount and CurrencyId to the Scalar valued Function as Input parameter   like this

```
[dbo].[function_Valued](@totalPayment,@fromCurencyId,@toCurrencyId)
```

And sum that values for instance  if we consider the table above

```
[dbo].[functin_scalar](550,USD,EU)=450
[dbo].[function_scalar](650,EU,EU)=650
Get total 1100
```

Put simply i want calculate sum amount and i need to  convert it in one currency.

Comment: You need [APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Could you please show how to do?I have not used apply yet .

Comment: The link I posted has all the information you need (even a nice example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to read the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754663/difference-between-scalar-table-valued-and-aggregate-functions-in-sql-server) 
to get more about the differences between Table Valued Function and Scalar function, which will help you to get more understanding on which method will work best in your situation.

Secondly, I'll post a simple scalar function and you need to modify it according to your needs:

```
CREATE FUNCTION TotalPayment 
(
    @Amount         DECIMAL(18,4), 
    @FromCurrency   CHAR(3),
    @ToCurrency     CHAR(3)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,4)
AS
BEGIN

    IF(@FromCurrency = 'USD' AND @ToCurrency = 'EUR')
    SET @Amount = @Amount * 0.803743

    IF(@FromCurrency = 'EUR' AND @ToCurrency = 'USD')
    SET @Amount = @Amount * 1.24418

    RETURN @Amount
END
GO
```

The function takes the amount with EUR as base currency, you could change that into your preferred currency. Also, you need to maintain the currency rate, as the market goes up and down in this matter, so you need to figure out a way to update the currency rate regularly . Unless your database has that data. If so, you can just select the rates from its table.

*Hint: declaring a new @param to get currency rate from another table will be useful.*

Then, you can use a simple SELECT statement

IF you need to convert all rows to EUR :

```
SELECT
    Amount, 
    Currencyid, 
    dbo.TotalPayment(Amount, CurrencyId, 'EUR') AS ConvertedToEUR
FROM  GetTotalPaymentAmount
```

IF you want to get only the total amount (after converted):

```
SELECT SUM(dbo.TotalPayment(Amount, CurrencyId, 'EUR')) AS TotalinEUR
FROM  GetTotalPaymentAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this (at the end) :-

```
SELECT [dbo].[function_scalar](TheSum, CurrencyId,EU) AS GrandTotal
FROM (
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TheSum, CurrencyId
FROM [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
WHERE OperationTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CurrencyId)
```

Comment: Getting error Invalid column name in variables TheSum and currencyid

Comment: Does the sub-query run?      SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TheSum, CurrencyId
FROM [dbo].[fn_DepositWithdrawReport]()
WHERE OperationTypeId = 2
GROUP BY CurrencyId