# Get monthly attendance for an employee

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that a guy helped here in developing which gives fine result. I want to use this query in a function which later I want to use in a procedure.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDays] (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @dateFrom datetime 
     DECLARE @dateTo datetime 
     SET @dateFrom = @StartDate 
     SET @dateTo = @EndDate


     DECLARE @DAYSWORKED INT   
     SELECT @DAYSWORKED = (
   SELECT EmpId,  COUNT(*) as DaysWorked 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT EmpId,CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) AS [Date]
      FROM myTable
      WHERE TimeIn IS NOT NULL
      AND CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )T
    GROUP BY EmpId
    ORDER BY EmpId)
RETURN ISNULL(@DAYSWORKED,0)

END
```

The very first error I am getting is that

```
Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fnGetWorkedDays, Line 24
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

I removed ORDER BY then I got another error says

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fnGetWorkedDays, Line 25
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

Comment: Errors are pretty clear. I guess you need to add a specific EmpId you are interested in. (And remove `Empid` from the select)

Comment: Actually, you should rewrite it as an inline table valued function. It's easier to use, and much more performant.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Could you be able to help out by providing any sample or query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to go though this to understand more on table valued functions vs scalar valued function [Difference between scalar, table-valued, and aggregate functions in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754663/difference-between-scalar-table-valued-and-aggregate-functions-in-sql-server)

Regarding your scenario, you should be writing a table values function for this like following.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDays]
 (
  @StartDate AS DATETIME,
  @EndDate datetime
 )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
   SELECT EmpId,  COUNT(*) as DaysWorked 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT EmpId,CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) AS [Date]
      FROM myTable
      WHERE TimeIn IS NOT NULL
      AND CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )T
    GROUP BY EmpId
```

To use the function you can write your queries like following.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '2018-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2018-01-31'
select * from  [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDays](@StartDate,@EndDate)
```

If you want this to work as a scalar value function, in that case you need to pass `EmpId` as parameter like following.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDaysEmpWise]
 (
  @StartDate AS DATETIME,
  @EndDate datetime,
  @EmpId INT
 )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RetunCount INT

      SELECT @RetunCount = COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(TimeIn AS DATE))
      FROM myTable
      WHERE TimeIn IS NOT NULL
      AND CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
      AND EmpID=@EmpId
      RETURN @RetunCount

  END
```

And you can use it directly in your select clause like following.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime
DECLARE @EndDate datetime
SET @StartDate = '2018-01-01'
SET @EndDate = '2018-01-31'
SELECT [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDaysEmpWise](@StartDate,@EndDate,1)
```

Comment: Best explanation ever

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for .?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetWorkedDays] (@StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime)
RETURNS @DaysWorked TABLE   
   (  
 Empid Int,   
    DaysWorked  Int   
   ) 
AS
BEGIN 


insert into @DaysWorked (Empid,DaysWorked)

  SELECT EmpId,  COUNT(*) as DaysWorked 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT EmpId,CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) AS [Date]
      FROM myTable
      WHERE TimeIn IS NOT NULL
      AND CAST(TimeIn AS DATE) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )T
    GROUP BY EmpId
    ORDER BY EmpId

     RETURN 
END

select * from [fnGetWorkedDays]('2018-01-01','2018-01-31')
```