# Why SQL function always returning empty result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Following `function` I have write which accept `xml` and returns `table` as result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest(@ID INT,@XML_Details xml)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE
(
    Value1 INT,
    Value2 INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
    (
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @RESULT(Value1,Value2)
    SELECT 
        l.v.value('Value2[1]','INT'),
        l.v.value('Value1[1]','INT')
    FROM @XML_Details.nodes('/Listings/listing')l(v)
    RETURN
END
```

And following is the code I using to run against above `function` but it always returning `Empty` result.

```
DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table
(
        Value1 INT,
        Value2 INT
)
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result
values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6)


DECLARE @xml_Temp xml

SET @xml_Temp = (   SELECT * 
                    FROM @tbl_xml_Result
                    FOR XML PATH('Listing'),ROOT('Listings')
                )

DELETE FROM @tbl_xml_Result
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result(Value1,Value2)
Select 
    T.Value1,
    T.Value2
FROM FunctionTest(1,@xml_Temp) T

select * from @tbl_Xml_Result
```

Comment: Please do not make edit that way (in fact asking whole new question). Your orignal problem has been solved. If you need futher assistance consider asking new question with http://sqlfiddle.com demo that **include your real schema** and data. [More info about chameleon questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all avoid multiline function when it is possible. [Inline UDFs have better pefromance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554333/multi-statement-table-valued-function-vs-inline-table-valued-function).

Second `XQuery` is case-sensitive and you don't have `'/Listings/listing'` path.

Third: you probably want to filter using `@ID`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION FunctionTest(@ID INT,@XML_Details xml)
RETURNS  TABLE
AS
RETURN(
    SELECT Value1, Value2
    FROM (SELECT  
            l.v.value('(Value2)[1]','INT') AS Value2,
            l.v.value('(Value1)[1]','INT') AS Value1
          FROM @XML_Details.nodes('/Listings/Listing')l(v)) AS sub
    WHERE Value1 = @ID
    )
GO

DECLARE @tbl_Xml_Result Table(Value1 INT,Value2 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl_xml_Result(Value1, Value2)
values(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5),(5,6);

DECLARE @xml_Temp xml  = (SELECT * 
                          FROM @tbl_xml_Result
                          FOR XML PATH('Listing'),ROOT('Listings'));

SELECT T.Value1,
       T.Value2
FROM FunctionTest(1,@xml_Temp) T;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/edit/PAH51391)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the 19th line of your function:

```
    FROM @XML_Details.nodes('/Listings/listing')l(v)
```

***l**isting - and you need **L**isting